# Sum elements of a list between two threads

Tags: python, multithreading, list

I'm trying to add the elements of a list in a dictionary:

```
if threading.current_thread().name == "Thread 1":
    print("I'm thread 1")
    for word in list_thread1:
        if word[0] in shared_dict:
            shared_dict[word[0]].append(1)
        else:
            shared_dict[word[0]] = [1]

if threading.current_thread().name == "Thread 2":
    print("I'm thread 2")
    for word in list_thread2:
        if word[0] in shared_dict:
            shared_dict[word[0]].append(1)
        else:
            shared_dict[word[0]] = [1]
```

I'm looping over the list and I look if the key is already on the dictionary, if the key exists, I append the number 1, if the key does not exists, I create the list [1]. But the problem I'm having is this error (only in when I use 2 threads):

```
    shared_dict[word[0]].append(1)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

and I don't know why. Can you explain what I'm doing bad?
Thanks

Comment: You almost certain need to use some locking if you're modifying the dictionary from two threads. Even if it doesn't solve this problem it'll solve future problems that you might not even notice, such as it effectively missing results by both threads encountering the same word at the same time and both setting `[1]` rather than one appending an extra `1`.

Comment: @Kemp Yes, I think you are right with this, but I tried to lock like this: 
            if word[0] in shared_dict:
                lock.acquire()
                shared_dict[word[0]].append(1)
                lock.release()
But the problem is not solved

Comment: `shared_dict[palabra1[0]].append(1)` is the error seems to refer to a different piece of code. Are you sure that this error is generated by the code you posted?

Comment: @LucaDiLiello That was a mistranscription

Comment: Could you please provide a runnable piece of code?

Comment: I just discovered the bug, the problem was in another piece of code and is about not join threads. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Chariot You have to acquire the lock *before* checking if the word is in the dictionary not afterwards, otherwise you've not fixed the issue I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I've discovered was about not joining the threads, so the thread continued execution and creating dataraces with the other thread